# Batch state update screws application logic

Tags: react-native, state

I have the following log-out related code which should reset all my global states. The 'setSignedIn(false)' line should go first so that the other state updates don't trigger anything in the currently-mounted screens.

```
            } else {
                console.log('This should only trigger if logged out');
                // Reset all global state variables
                setSignedIn(false)
                setUserId()
                setMatchScreenChild1State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild2State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild3State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild4State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild5State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild1MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild2MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild3MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild4MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild5MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild1MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild2MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild3MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild4MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild5MatchedUserData()
                setProfileScreenState('loading')
                setChats({})
                setMatchInvitesMatchIds([])
                setActiveMatchIds([])
                setSignUpCompleted()
            }
```

Then later I have conditional React Navigation rendering. As you see, if signedIn === false, then the other screens are not mounted. So it is safe to trigger the global state updates because nothing will be triggered there as the screens are no longer mounted.

```
            {signedIn===false ?
            <Stack.Screen name="authenticationFlow" component={authenticationFlow} options={{ title: 'Sign Up' }} />
            : signedIn===true && signUpCompleted===true ?
            <Stack.Screen name="mainFlow" component={mainFlow} options={{ title: 'Main Flow' }} />
            : signedIn===true && signUpCompleted===false ?
            <Stack.Screen name="userDetails" component={userDetailsFlow} options={{ title: 'User Details' }} />
            : null }
```

But what happens right now is that the 'setProfileScreenState('loading')', which is one of the last lines in the state updates, is still triggered when 'setSignedIn(false)' has not completed yet. As a result, a useEffect is triggered which gives an error somewhere in my code.

How can I get setSignedIn(false) to go first before the other state updates? Do I really need to do something like this for this seemingly common use case..?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (signedIn === false) {
        setUserId()
        setMatchScreenChild1State('notReady')
        setMatchScreenChild2State('notReady')
        setMatchScreenChild3State('notReady')
        setMatchScreenChild4State('notReady')
        setMatchScreenChild5State('notReady')
        setMatchScreenChild1MatchData()
        setMatchScreenChild2MatchData()
        setMatchScreenChild3MatchData()
        setMatchScreenChild4MatchData()
        setMatchScreenChild5MatchData()
        setMatchScreenChild1MatchedUserData()
        setMatchScreenChild2MatchedUserData()
        setMatchScreenChild3MatchedUserData()
        setMatchScreenChild4MatchedUserData()
        setMatchScreenChild5MatchedUserData()
        setProfileScreenState('loading')
        setChats({})
        setMatchInvitesMatchIds([])
        setActiveMatchIds([])
        setSignUpCompleted()
    }
}, [signedIn])
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state (see below for details).

more information [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

Use [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to manage your global state.

Comment: Please see my comment below, tried to implement your solution but without success...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use solution in docmurloc's link but it gives the same issue. That documentation is for setState whereas I am using useState hooks.. Perhaps that solution does not work for useState?

```
                function signOut() {
                  setSignedIn((state) => {
                    // Important: read `state` instead of `this.state` when updating.
                    return false
                  })
                }
                signOut()

                setUserId()
                setMatchScreenChild1State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild2State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild3State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild4State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild5State('notReady')
                setMatchScreenChild1MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild2MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild3MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild4MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild5MatchData()
                setMatchScreenChild1MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild2MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild3MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild4MatchedUserData()
                setMatchScreenChild5MatchedUserData()
                setProfileScreenState('loading')
                setChats({})
                setMatchInvitesMatchIds([])
                setActiveMatchIds([])
                setSignUpCompleted()
```